# Proving a quadratic inequality

Tags: inequality

Given that $(x+y)^2 \geq 4xy$, then prove $1/x^2 + 1/y^2 \geq 4/(x^2 + y^2)$.

I have tried taking the reciprocal, squaring, square rooting, expanding, factoring and various other algebraic manipulation but nothing has worked so far.

The question seems to be structured in a way which suggests that I should be manipulating the first inequality (which is already given) to produce the second inequality. Does anyone know how to do this

Comment: What strategies do you know to prove inequalities?

Comment: Hint: $(x+y)^2 \geq 4xy$ is trivially true for all real numbers. Unsurprisingly, so is the other inequality.

Comment: I have tried taking the reciprocal, squaring, square rooting, expanding, factoring and various other algebraic manipulation but nothing has worked so far.

Comment: Did you try multiplying throughout? What do you get then? Alternatively, what happens when you "make common denominator" for the LHS?

Comment: The question seems to be structured in a way which suggests that I should be manipulating the first inequality (which is already given) to produce the second inequality. Does anyone know how to do this

Comment: I'd rather manipulate the second to get the first. And revert the process when _writing_ (not _finding_) a solution, if needed.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** The first inequality is equivalent to $ (x-y)^2 \geq 0 $.

**Hint:** After making common denominators, the second inequality is equivalent to $( x^2 - y^2 )^2 \geq  0$ (with $xy \neq 0$ to account for the denominators).

Comment: You mean $(x^2-y^2)^2 \geqslant 0$? You seem to be missing a power of two.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the first statement. Just apply $AM ≥ HM$ on the second statement:

$$\frac{1/x^2 + 1/y^2}{2} ≥ \frac{2}{x^2 + y^2}$$

since $\frac{1}{x^2}, \frac{1}{y^2} > 0$.

Answer (score 0):

We can not  make it because it's wrong! Try $x=0$.

The condition gives $$y^2\geq0,$$ which is true, but the statement, which we need to prove is wrong

because we can not  divide by $0$.

For $xy>0$ we obtain:
$$(x+y)^2\geq4xy$$ it's $$\frac{x^2+2xy+y^2}{xy}\geq4$$ or
$$\frac{x}{y}+1+\frac{y}{x}+1\geq4$$ or
$$(x+y)\left(\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{y}\right)\geq4.$$
Now, after replacing $x$ on $x^2$ and $y$ on $y^2$ we obtain:
$$(x^2+y^2)\left(\frac{1}{x^2}+\frac{1}{y^2}\right)\geq4$$ or 
$$\frac{1}{x^2}+\frac{1}{y^2}\geq\frac{4}{x^2+y^2}.$$